# How to remove highlight and dimming for MudChip?

Tags: c#, blazor, mudblazor

By default when you hover over not-disabled `MudChip`, it is highlighted. When you hover over disabled one, it is not. However the disabled one is dimmed.

In my case (i.e. for my eyes) the dimmed effect is too strong, I would like to have full readability even if the element is disabled.

How to get (rid of) both features -- no highlight when mouse hovers over, and no dimming.

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to do this? I am wondering the same.

Comment: @RyanWatson, no, this issue plus the fact that AFAIR button names are out of blue written in upper case led me to rolling out my own controls. Rationale -- if I have a library and I am forced to hack through CSS just to disable weird defaults,  I could as well write my own from scratch and learn CSS as the effect. And I don't regret this decision despite CSS frustrating as hell -- it is broken even with "new" elements like flex. Today I would consider more seriously FluentUI by MS (evidently MS will invest in this library more and more).